# OpenLayers vector layer from GeoServer does not appear completely

Tags: geoserver, openlayers

I have successfully loaded the vector layer but the webpage only shows parts of it, some are not displayed. Any idea what might be the cause?

[image]

```
    var jsonSource_testLayer_1 = new ol.source.Vector({
    url: 'http://localhost:8080/geoserver/Testing1/ows?service=WFS&version=1.0.0&request=GetFeature&typeName=Testing1%3AtestLayer&maxFeatures=50&outputFormat=application%2Fjson',
    format: new ol.format.GeoJSON(),
});

var lyr_testLayer_1 = new ol.layer.Vector({
    source: jsonSource_testLayer_1,

    style: style_testLayer_1,
    title: '<img src="styles/legend/testLayer_1.png" /> testLayer'

});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, GeoServer only delivers 10000 features on a WFS GetFeature request. You have configured it to deliver only 50. So you may want to change `&maxfeatures=50` to something like `&maxfeatures=20000`. 20000 is a good setting because it is the maximum that OpenLayers can render smoothly on an average machine when zoomed out.

Comment: thank you so much. your reply solve my problem.